# Read First line from a file stored in Azure Cloud Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to read the First line of the file, the file is stored in Azure Storage Blob Container. Below code snippet is standard code to read a file till end and write the content:

```
 foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

                using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine().First());
                            //Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

I want the first line of file. But I cannot use "while (!reader.EndOfStream)" as it reads whole file and then writes to console line by line.
Also I cannot load the whole file as the file size is more than 3GB.

How do I get hold of only the first line from the file stored in Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Blob Storage supports reading byte ranges. So you don't really need to download the entire blob to read just the first line in the file. The method you would want to use is [`CloudBlob.DownloadRangeToByteArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetobytearray).

Let's assume that the lines in the blob are separated by `Line Feed (\n or character code 10)`. With this assumption here's what you would need to do:

You could choose to progressively read just a single byte starting from 0th byte in a loop. You store the the byte you read in some kind of byte buffer. You will continue to read till the time you encounter this line feed character. As soon as you encounter this, you would break out of the loop. Whatever you have in the buffer will be your first line.

Instead of reading a single byte, you could also read a larger byte range (say 1024 bytes or may be larger). Once you get these bytes, you would look for this new line character in the byte range download. If you find this character, you would split the array to the index of this character and that would be your first line. If you don't encounter this character, you will put the data fetched in some kind of buffer and you will read next 1K bytes. You will continue doing this till the time you encounter this new line character. Once you find it, you will use the buffer plus the last set of bytes received and that would be your first line.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage blobs are not the same as local file objects. If you want to do specific parsing of a blob, you need to copy it locally first, and then open it as a proper file. And yes, for a 3GB file, given the 60MB/s per-blob transfer rate, this could take some time. (so you might want to consider storing parts of the blob, such as the first line, in a secondary, searchable storage area, for these purposes).

Comment: How will I know the output read by reader from a big file is given a small parts of the blob. How to read in small blocks for blob? I have tried the ReadBlock code but there I need to specify the # of characters. This character length I cannot specify as I just want to read the first line and then skip the loop..

Answer (score 0):

Although a year late and I have not tried it but instead of using

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine().First());
}
```

have you tried this

```
if(!reader.EndOfStream)
{
   Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
}
```